# Google Maps not showing despite setting parent div width and height to 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

I know there are plenty of posts with the same title and I went through as many of them as possible. Basically, I am trying to show a Google map inside a div whose height and width I have set to 100%, but the map is not showing. I tried to set the height and width of the `<html>` and `<body>` to 100% as well but the map still did not show. My relevant code is given below:

```
<body>
    <div class="section">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;">
                <div id="map-canvas"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="well">               
                <div class="panel-group" id="Accordion"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

...

<script>

    var spinner = new Spinner();
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var place = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("selectedplace"));
        console.log(place);
        if (place == null){ 
            ...
        }else{   
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',loadMap);     
            getQueuesAtPlace(place["id"]);
        }
    });
</script>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function loadMap() {

    var source = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentplace"));
    var destination = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("selectedplace"));

    var lat = destination['latitude'];
    var long = destination['longitude'];
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat), parseFloat(long)),
        zoom: 8
        //mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    console.log("CENTER: " + mapOptions.center);
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat),parseFloat(long)),
        map: map,
        title: 'Office location'
    });

}
```

The JS part of the code is mostly copy-paste, so I think the mistake is in the positioning/style of the div. Ideally, I would like to have the map inside the `<well>` tag as well, but it's not showing anywhere. Can anyone point out the mistake?

Comment: try giving it fixed height atleast, is it really working? then you can go for 100% width and height

Comment: I set height to 30px and it did not work. The style I have in my post was found from another post.

Comment: then we'll need an active fiddle

Comment: What does your CSS look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a fixed height to the element with id **map-canvas** just to see if its working